# match RFC 4646 language codes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I am using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in my angular 2 application. It expects me to define a language to use as well as a fallback language. eg

```
this.translate.setDefaultLang("se");
this.translate.use("se-SV);
```

**Problem: I need to pick which strings to use.** I have an "input" of the language I want to support (based on some data I fetch from somewhere) and I have a given amount of translation files on my server:

eg `[ "en-GB", "sv", "sv-SV" ]`

**Given I know what language code I need to support how do I pick which of these files to use?**

**Is there an angular 2 package for this? (or maybe some support in ngx-translate that I missed)**

For example:

```
se-FI -> use: "se" backup: either nothing or "en", don't care
se-SV -> use: "se-SV" backup: "se"
en-US -> use: "en-GB"
```

I've already written my own code to do this. So if these examples were unit tests they'd pass. But I feel like I shouldn't have to write this, and I know that there are edge cases (like chinese) where this naive approach breaks down. (because the split between simplified and tradition isn't really reflected by RFC 4646)